# Method for splitting groups multiple times into different sized smaller groups with as little overlap as possible

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking for a method for splitting up groups of people multiple times into smaller groups such that there is as little overlap in the smaller groups as possible. In other words, as much as possible, people should meet with new people and avoid meeting with people they have met with before. (It is not essential that all people meet with everyone else in the group. The goal is just that they don't meet with the same people repeatedly.)

I saw another post with the answer for how to divide a group of 30 people into groups of 6 for a total of 7 meetings.

My challenge is similar, though slightly different in that I am faced with this situation repeatedly with different numbers of people and groups, and the smaller groups sometimes need to be different sizes.

For example, this week I have a group of 10 people that I would like to divide into smaller groups 7 times, like this:

- Meeting 1: 3 smaller groups of 3, 3 and 4 people
- Meeting 2: 5 smaller groups of 2 people
- Meeting 3: 4 smaller groups of 2, 2, 3 and 3 people
- Meeting 4: 5 smaller groups of 2 people
- Meeting 5: 5 smaller groups of 2 people
- Meeting 6: 5 smaller groups of 2 people
- Meeting 7: 3 smaller groups of 3, 3 and 4 people
- Meeting 8: 2 smaller groups of 5 people

Every week, the numbers are different. There is a different total number of people in the group, different number of times to be broken down into smaller groups, different number of people in each of the smaller groups. Sometimes I don’t know in advance the total number of meetings there will be, sometimes one person is absent for a particular meeting, or sometimes other things change in the middle of the whole process. For example, the requirements in the above example could change after meeting 7 such that instead of needing 2 smaller groups of 5 people for meeting 8, I might need 3 smaller groups of 3, 3, 4 people. Therefore, it would be great to be able to determine the groups one by one as they are needed, and to be able to change the parameters without the system forgetting what was done before.

I would love to have a software where I could just plug in the total number of people and the number of smaller groups I need, and then get a list of how to divide the group each time. The system would need to remember which people have been together already until all the meetings are over.

Even better would be if the system could store multiple groups at the same time. In other words, if I have 2 groups with 10 people each that both need to have 8 meetings such as in the example above, the system could keep track of the “blue group” meetings and the “red group” meetings separately.

I do this kind of grouping manually on a regular basis, and it works well enough, though it is kind of annoying and time-consuming. Depending on the parameters of a particular group, I know that it is impossible to avoid having some people meet in the smaller groups more than once. However, it seems like an algorithm or software would do it better (and certainly faster) than I can do it manually.

In terms of my skills, I’m not a programmer or mathematician, but I was always good at math in school. I’m also a quick learner and don’t mind putting in some effort if it will lead to a good solution to this challenge.

I would be grateful for anyone who has any suggestions! Thank you in advance! :-)

P.S. I looked at the list of existing tags, and being a lay person, I wasn't sure which tags would be appropriate. Being a new user to this forum without a "1000 reputation" I was forced to pick an existing tag, so I took my best guess. So if anyone has a suggestion for a better tag that I can add that will help me get this question to the right person, I would also appreciate that as well!